# add current page class to body tag name from section class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was tryng to add the current page class name to body tag
example `<body class="page-2>`when i scroll down or up to sections

in the example currently it is adding class to each section, works perfectly but I need it to be added to the body class.

Here's the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var pages = $(".page").length,
    scrolling = false,
    curPage = 1

  function pagination(page, movingUp) {
    scrolling = true
    var diff = curPage - page,
      oldPage = curPage
    curPage = page
    $(".page").removeClass("active small previous")

    $(".page-" + page).addClass("active")

    $(".nav-btn").removeClass("active")
    $(".nav-page" + page).addClass("active")
    if (page > 1) {
      $(".page-" + (page - 1)).addClass("previous")

      if (movingUp) {
        $(".page-" + (page - 1)).hide()

        var hackPage = page
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(".page-" + (hackPage - 1)).show()
        }, 600)
      }
      while (--page) {
        $(".page-" + page).addClass("small")
      }
    }

    // console.log(diff)
    if (diff > 1) {
      for (var j = page + 1; j < oldPage; j++) {
        $(".page-" + j + " .half").css("transition", "transform .7s ease-out")
      }
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      scrolling = false
      $(".page .half").attr("style", "")
      $(".page")
    }, 700)
  }

  function navigateUp() {
    if (curPage > 1) {
      curPage--
      pagination(curPage, true)
    }
  }

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage < pages) {
      curPage++
      pagination(curPage)
    }
  }

  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
    if (!scrolling) {
      if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        navigateUp()
      } else {
        navigateDown()
      }
    }
  })

 

  

 
  
})
```

```css
section {
  height:100vh
}

.page-2{
  background-color:#ccc
}
```

```html
<section class="page page-1 active">
  <p>Section 1</p>
</section>
   
   
<section class="page page-2 ">
  <p>Section 2</p>
</section>
   
   
<section class="page page-3 ">
  <p>Section 3</p>
</section>
   
   
   
   
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, i need to add the current page class name to body tag
example `<body class="page-2>`

currently is adding the active class

Comment: Why not using `$("body").addClass()`?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios It doesn't work